How to stop execution until future is completed
Context
I have main method:
void main() {
  setupBeforeRun();   // <--- this is important
  runApp(const App());
}


void setupBeforeRun() {
  DependencyInjection.configure(); // <--- here I set up DB object
  DependencyInjection.get<DictionaryService>().getDictionaries(); // <-- here I am using it
}


in DependencyInjection I just create Storage instance:

class StorageService {
  late Database _db;

  StorageService() {
    var future = initDb().then((value) => _db = value);
  }

  Future<Database> initDb() async {
    if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
      sqfliteFfiInit();
      databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    }

    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'my.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) => _createTables(db, version),
      version: 1,
    );
  }


Challenge
I want to stop my app until _db is properly initialised.
Otherwise I randomly received error Field '_db@24081564 has not been initialized.
I'm using async here because openDatabase is async.
What not work
bool isNotComplited = true
var future = initDb().then((value) => _db = value).whenComplited(isNotComplited = false);

while(isNotComplited){}


It just hang all app and future is never completed.
Question
How to wait for future till its complete and then continue?
I don't care about latency of waiting , initialised db is more important for me. Above code is just an example. I want to know
how to stop and wait for future to complete in synchronous function?

"how to stop and wait for future to complete in synchronous function?" you can't.  Once you have promises and futures, anything that consumes them must be prepared to offer varying results depending on whether the future is completed or not.

I would suggest you to register your StorageService with registerLazySingletonAsync.
To do that you have to create an async method, which returns your StorageService.
class StorageService {
  late Database _db;

  // Calling this method will initialize your Database
  // and returns the corresponding StorageService.
  Future<StorageService> init() async {
    _db = await initDb();
  }
}

Now you register your Service with GetIt.
class DependencyInjection {
  static void configure() {
    GetIt.registerLazySingletonAsync<DictionaryService>(
      () => StorageService().init(),
    );
  }
}

You can then retrieve your StorageService by doing the following:
final storageService = await GetIt.getAsync<StorageService>();
final dictionaries = storageService.getDictionaries();

